# Is Marquis de Sade credited in Salò?

Tags: credits, salo-or-the-120-days-of-sodom

Is Marquis de Sade not credited in Pasolini's *Salò, or the 120 Days of Sodom*, or did I miss his name?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**No.** There is no credit.

From [IMDB - Salò, or the 120 Days of Sodom (1975)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0073650/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast)

[image]